# Xcode iOS: Convert int to NSString

Tags: ios, xcode, nsstring, int

I'm trying to grab avalue from a UIPicker which is populated with round numbers, integers pulled from and NSMutableArray. I'm trying to convert the pulled values to an actual int.

I tried this in the .m:

```
int pickednumber;


......

-(void) pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component{


NSString *numbers = [arrayNumbers objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]];

pickednumber = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", numbers];

NSLog(@"Picked number %@ ", numbers); 

}
```

I get the error in the pickednumber = line: Incompatible pointer to integer conversion assigning to 'int' from 'id'.
What am i doing wrong?

Message was edited by Sounddesigner on 3/8/12 at 3:05 PM

Comment: Question and title don't seem to match.

Comment: These days it's just ...

`NSString *str = [@(number) stringValue];`

it's that simple

http://stackoverflow.com/a/21258535/294884

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSString *intString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", myInt];
```

http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=448594

Comment: title doesn't match. but glad that Giel & dotoree are in sync and the problem got solved :)

Answer (score 95):

`NSString` has a **convinience** method to get **integer value** of a text

do this

```
pickednumber = [numbers intValue];

NSLog(@"Picked number %d ", numbers);  // not %@ ..%@ is for objects .. not int
```

Answer (score 3):

To convert integer to NSString:

```
NSString *string  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",integerNumber];
```

To convert NSString to int:

```
int number = [string integerValue];
```