# Converting int into NSString

Tags: iphone, nsstring, int

I want to convert a random int number in the `NSString` and then assign the NSString to another `NSString` but it crashes the app

I am doing the following

```
int mynumber =(arc4random() % 1000 );

unique = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",mynumber];

   NSLog(unique)

   NSString*test=unique;
```

it gives crash when i write last line;

It also prints values when I nslog the `unique` string.

Comment: Refer:[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3574632]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3574632/how-to-convert-an-int-to-nsstring

Answer (score 101, accepted):

If you want to change the int to string

```
NSString *strFromInt = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",yourintvalue];
```

Answer (score 56):

This also works:

```
NSString *str = [@(number) stringValue];
```

Or, if you prefer dot notation:

```
NSString *str = @(number).stringValue;
```

This will box the primitive value to a `NSNumber` using the expression boxing syntax `@(...)`, then use its' `stringValue` method to convert it to `NSString`. This should also work for other primitive values (`NSInteger`, `float`, `double`, `long`, ...).

Comment: is there an dis-/advantage over the `stringWithFormat` syntax?

Comment: The advantage here is that this works for any primitive type, you don't need to explicitly set the format parameter. 


Also, I find this more concise and understandable, but this is a matter of taste. 


This was made possible with the expression boxing syntax, introduced in XCode 4.4

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *anotherStr;
int myNumber = (arc4random() % 1000 );
NSString *stringNum = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", myNumber];
anotherStr = stringNum; //assign NSString to NSString
// Here you can convert NSString to Int if you want.
NSLog(@"My number as NSString = %@", stringNum);
int getNumFromString = [stringNum intValue];

NSLog(@"My number from NSString = %i", getNumFromString);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have used NSLog statement incorrectly.It should have been used like below.

`NSLog(@"%@",unique);`